# Where does Word keep its autorecover data?

Tags: data-recovery, microsoft-word-2007

I accidentally closed Word withous saving a file. I had autorecover enabled. I immediately realised my mistake and pulled the plug on the computer and connected the hdd to another. How can I recover my document (t was not saved beforehand)

EDIT: I found parts of the document in the ~WRS and ~WRF files. Th e problem is to persuade Word to reconstruct the original, like it does with Autorecovery…

Comment: If word does not offer to restore the document the. The restoration file does not exit. It exits in the Appdata directory if you feel like looking for the non-existing file

Comment: @Ramhound I had AutoRecover set to 1 minute. I am fine with recovering deleted files.

Comment: You don't say whether Word offered to save the file when you closed Word. If it did and you declined, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: @kinokijuf - As I point out.  If word does not offer to restore the file its there isnt a recovery file to recover

Answer (score 1):

You can see the autorecover path in the `options` > `save` window. Try to search for your files there. 
[image: Word 2007 save window in options]

Also, you can try other recovery methods described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827099) (it's too long to copy to here).

Comment: -1 the `.asd` file contains the first version of my document. I’m positive that i had AutoRecover enabled.

Comment: "the first version"? You said you haven't saved the file, so there is only one version. And you've asked for the autorecover saving path. If it was enabled and working, the file should be there. If it isn't, there isn't any other place to look at.

Comment: The .asd file is a very early version of the file.

Comment: Then I'm sorry for you, but I don't think that you will be able to recover your file :\. Again, autorecovery files are in one place. If they are missing, you won't find them anywhere else.